# Is it possible to set up a rolling average for only one series of the dygraph

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I have tried using rollPeriod as a per-series property in order to display one "raw" time series and then its rolling average as a separate series, with no success. Is there a way to do this ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not. If you want to average one series but not another, you'll need to do it before you send the data to dygraphs.

Answer (score 2):

It's a pretty trivial fix to get this working, please see my pull request

[GitHub](https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/pull/811/files)